# How does a dynamic disk image work?

Tags: virtual-machine, filesystems, hypervisor

I was curious about the inner workings of virtualized computing.

Most hypervisors, including VirtualBox and Hyper-V, just to cite a couple, have the option of creating a dynamic image for disk drives. These images start from 0 byte size to be progressively increased in size to fit the data that is being put onto the hard drive until it's filled.

So I can expect a freshly installed Windows XP image occupies no more than 600MB on my host machine's disk.

I didn't know exactly how and where to search for technical documentation about this feature.

In theory, if you (the hypervisor system) can track files that are being written and deleted from a (virtual) disk then you can physically allocate on your host drive only the portion needed to store the data.

But in practice: hypervisors **must** be filesystem-agnostic, providing low-level APIs (virtual disk controller) to allow the virtualized OS to `physically` address a `virtual` drive; and modern filesystems only delete files by deleting their metadata from partition table, not by wiping their physical space.

The second case is of interest because if I were to write a virtual ATA controller I could apply a fast compression algorithm, like assume large blocks of zeroes as free space and deallocating them from the physical image file when the virtualized OS frees space. I don't have the knowledge to write such low-level code but I attended some advanced classes on virtualization.

#### The question is

how does a dynamic expansion disk work, given the filesystem agnosticity of a hypervisor and the fact that hardware disk access is performed based on physical-mapped-to-virtual sectors?

In particular, how does the hypervisor behave when the virtualized OS deletes files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File systems are mappings of files to 512 byte or 4k on disk blocks. For dynamic disks the hypervisor creates it's own mapping of "real" disk blocks to on disk data. The virtualized mapping of VM data to disk blocks for dynamic disks would look like FS on VM -> Hypervisor Mapping -> File on bare metal -> Block on physical disk.

Each time a write to a un-mapped block occurs the hypervisor appends that block to some file (*The dynamic disk*) and then annotates that append operation to it's mapping of "real" disk blocks to virtualized disk blocks.

When a delete occurs, the VM updates the metadata representing that file and then completes it's task. No actual delete occurs and the dynamic disk is the same size it was before the delete operation.

*How a VM could free data:* SSDs have introduced a notion of TRIM support which is a way of notifying the disk drive which blocks have been deleted and are no longer needed. Hypervisors could provide virtualized TRIM support to free blocks in the same way a SSD would free it's mapping of virtualized blocks to flash. Of course your OS would need to support TRIM, etc. etc. And... Even if hypervisors supported this, removing a chunk of data from a file is a non-trivial task.

Moof!